# How to force the number of digits in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

For instance

```
5 / 2 = 2.5
```

What I want is to force it to 4 digits:

```
5 / 2 = 2.5000
1 / 2 = 0.5000
10 / 10 = 1.0000
```

I tried to use round(5/2, 4) but it does not work.

Comment: It does not work because the zeroes in the end does not logically make sense. You might need string formatting for this

Comment: `"%0.4f" % (5/2.0)`

Comment: Also, round() works as expected. 2.5 rounded for 4 digits is exactly 2.5.